# Git push over ssh fails on windows with 'the remote end hung up unexpectedly' error

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm hoping someone can help me, as I've been fighting with this for days, and am stumped. I've set up the standard git client (from git-scm.com) on a brand new laptop running Windows 10, and am working on a repository hosted on Github.com.

Initially, I ran into some conflicts in the SSH configuration, due to the native Windows OpenSSH client fighting with the bundled SSH client, that comes with git. So authentication was failing. This, I've managed to solve by explicitly setting the global `sshCommand` config value as per [Adam Ralph's suggestion](https://adamralph.com/2018/05/15/windows-10-version-1803-broke-my-git-ssh/). This got me past authentication issues, and I'm able to clone, fetch, and pull from GitHub just fine. However, I'm not running into the following error, when I try to push.

```
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 3.20 KiB | 252.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 15 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've been scouring google and stackoverflow, and tried every solution I could find:

- Set the `http.postbuffer` value to 500MB - 1GB (though my repo has no large files, just a handful of small typescript files)
- Fully uninstalled the built-in Windows OpenSSH client
- Installed various versions of the Git client 2.17.1, 2.19.2, 2.20.1 (current latest version)
- Did some sanity checks, by attempting the same `git push` commands with subsets of the same added/changed files on a couple of other computers running Windows 10 Pro, with the same repository
- Re-installed the git client, disabling LFS support and then ran `git filter-branch` on the repo to clean up the repo
- Attempted multiple re-clones of the repo to a fresh folder
- Attempted changing over to use HTTPS instead of SSH. This seems to be the only way to unblock pushing to my GitHub repo
- Turned on more verbose logging via setting the sshCommand to `ssh -vv`. That updates the console logging to block down below.

At this point, I can unblock being able to actually do work by switching over to HTTPS remote connections, but I've never had issues like this using SSH in the several years that I've been using git. Has anyone run into something like this? Is there something obvious I'm missing.

```
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-f43b814b
debug1: no match: babeld-f43b814b
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/John/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_rsa (0x600061250)
debug2: key: /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_xmss (0x0)
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:0imySt9BYYbsr5CLqXP5JRHwHNCXAYuotf8/6WGE4sU /c/Users/John/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:0imySt9BYYbsr5CLqXP5JRHwHNCXAYuotf8/6WGE4sU
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.253.112]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending command: git-receive-pack 'john-shaskin/polly-notes-reader.git'
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects:  13% (2/15)   1248163Writing objects:   6% (1/15)
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 3.20debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0 KiB | 192.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 15 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
pectedlychannel 0: output drain -> closedfatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unex
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
Transferred: sent 6880, received 2096 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 13415.2, received 4087.0
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This, I've managed to solve by explicitly setting the global sshCommand config value as per Adam Ralph's suggestion.

Yes, but no: try first to use Git in a CMD session where you have put a simplified PATH, one in which the Git bundled openSSH will comes first and with be used (OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019) instead of the older one from Windows

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

git config --gobal --unset core.sshCommand
cd C:\path\to\repo
git config --local --unset core.sshCommand
```

Then try again, in that CMD session, for testing if the SSH issue persists.

Answer (score 2):

The connection is closed after writing a few bytes,
target https://github.com/john-shaskin/polly-notes-reader
Try the following:

run git bash(Do not use openssh, use git bash only) for windows, and enter the following commands

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
git config --global ssh.postBuffer 524288000
```

use simple settings for git push

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

change folder to repository you want to commit

```
cd /{driveletter}/{rootdir}/{repo}/{src}

cd /d/projects/repo/src <---- change accordingly.
```

now try

```
git push
```

If you still get the error, you need to enable GIT_TRACE_PACKET=true and GIT_TRACE=2, post the error log here again, I'll help you through it.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry but I have to inform you that 'fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly' this message is mostly comes from remote end as its says.

- Your data assets cause crash at remote end (even it could happen with github)
- SSH Timeouts, see: `ServerAliveInterval`
- Your connection not properly fit with TLS protocol, ie: MTU size invalid (some ISPs using GRE tunnels) try lower MTU: 1436
- You can use wireshark to trace down what triggers the TCP abortion due you are communicating over TCP Protocol, also wireshark can decode some SSH packets as well.